# How can I make Two JSF components communicate using Listener and Event

Tags: jsf, broadcast, custom-component, event-listener

I have two jsf **custom-components** which are supposed to communicate. 
These components are a DataTable and a pager.
I am looking for that when changing the model of the DataTable, an event triggers to allow the pager to be updated, and vice versa. and that maintaining their independence. is it possible to do so using the listener and the event?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, pass the pager as property of the listener or just let the pager itself implement `FacesListener`.

Comment: I'm afraid it is not clear to me. Can you give me an example?